# Modx ссылка на предыдущую страницу

Tags: php, modx, link

В modx revo2 нужно сделать ссылку, которая будет возвращать на ту страницу, с которой попали на эту ссылку. Пока придумал только как вернуть на родителя, но это не то что нужно:
 `href="[[!++site_url]][[~[[*parent]]]]"`

Как реализовать нужную мне ссылку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот таким нехитрым сниппетом вполне себе получилось:

**Сниппет:**

```
[[!Referer]]
```

**Код сниппета:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['referId'])){
    $referId = $_SESSION['referId'];
}else{
    $referId = 0;   
}

$thisId = $modx->resource->get('id');
$_SESSION['referId'] = $thisId;

if($referId){
    $url = $modx->makeUrl($referId);  
    return '<a href="'.$url.'">Назад</a>';
}else{
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="button" onclick="history.back();" value="Назад"/>
```

или
`<a href="javascript:history.back();">Назад</a>`

Answer (score 2):

В крайнем случае - создать сниппет, возвращающий `HTTP['REFERRER']`. Но сперва стоит поиска встроенные средства на тему конкретно этого заголовка, заголовок вообще и только потом велосипедить.